# How can I loop through the function random amount of times?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, canvas, random

I'm trying to create a random amount of squares on canvas each time I press the button and then I want them to move up. Right now it completely ignores the for loop and only generates one square instead of random amount. How to solve this?

```
// Spawn
var numberArray = [0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360, 420];
var posX = numberArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * numberArray.length)];
var posY = 240;

  function spawnRandomObject() {
    // Game Object
      ctx.fillStyle = '#f2a365';
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, 60, 60);
      ctx.stroke();
  }


// Blocks moving up
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Spawn random amount of objects
  for (var i=0; i<Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1); i++){
     spawnRandomObject(i);
  }
  posY -=60;
});
```

Comment: `posX` is only evaluated once. It has the same value each time you call the function. Move `var posX = numberArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * numberArray.length)];` to inside the function.

Comment: Also, note that the conditional in the `for` is evaluated before each loop iteration - changing the value you test `i` against each time.

Comment: Put the random number of iterations in a variable before the loop, then compare with the variable in the `for()` loop.

Comment: There's no need to use an array. All the elements are just multiples of `60`. So use `posX = 60 * Math.floor(8 * Math.random());`

Answer (score 0):

Your function has no parameters:
`function spawnRandomObject()`
but when you call it you are passing one:
`spawnRandomObject(i);`
Maybe that was meant to be parameter

The other thing I see is that you are correctly calling the function a random number of times,
but the function is drawing the rectangle at the same location:
`ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, 60, 60);`
you set the `posX, posY` at the beginning and they do not change.
So yes you do draw multiple just on top of each other

Maybe you meant to do something like this:

```js
function spawnRandomObject(x, y, w, h) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.stroke();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() + 1) * 8)
for (var i = 0; i < rand; i++) {
  spawnRandomObject(i*15, i*8, 10, 10);
  spawnRandomObject((rand-i)*8, i*6, 5, 5);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```